# Finding out co-linear points

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

> How many triangles with positive area can be drawn on the coordinate
>   plane such that the vertices have integer coordinates $(x,y)$ satisfying
>   $1≤x≤3$ and $1≤y≤3$?

It is easy that we have  nine possible ways to connect the coordinated to make  triangles. But  is there any easy way to get the number of co-nonlinear points?

If you draw for me, it be be really a big help

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are 9 possible points. So you have ${9\choose 3} = 84$ ways yo choose 3 distinct vertexes. Out of those, $8$ of them would require to select three vertexes aligned (three horizontal lines, three vertical ones and the two main diagonals).

So you have $84 - 8 = 76$ possible triangles.

Comment: "three horizontal lines, three vertical ones and the two main diagonals" how?

Comment: Like this: http://gyazo.com/ab88e53f05cbc7f57ed50428fa8ad059

If all the tree vertexes are on any of this lines, you don't have a triangle.